# Adding values in ASP.NET controller ​from the SQL Server database column for a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My problem: I need to add 'overtime' for all previous months from the beginning of the year to the month selected.

My table in SQL Server:

Overtime : `varchar(20)`

```
Id | Login | Year | Month | Day | Overtime
---+-------+------+-------+-----+----------
 1 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  1  |  08:00
 2 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  2  |  08:00
 3 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  3  |  07:30
 4 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  4  |  12:00
...
30 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  30 |  04:00
...
41 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  1  |  08:00
42 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  2  |  08:00
43 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  3  |  07:30
44 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  4  |  12:00
...
52 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  25 |  04:00
```

So if the user chose March (3) and year 2020 (in dropdownlist), this function must extract the aggregated information from the overtime column of the previous months of the selected year.

(that is, in the example for January (1) and February (2) and for 2020)

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartialTableEcp()  //change nothing
{
    // Data is already extracted from other operations
    // So e.g. user enters chooses year: 2020 month: March (3) 
    int numberMonth= 3;
    int numberYear= 2020;
    int numberOfDays= 31;

    // person identification by login
    var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    // retrieve all month records from the table, (i dont know it works)
    var existingRecords = _tableEcpContext.Karta
                                          .Where(x => x.Login == userName && 
                                                      x.Year == numberYear && 
                                                      x.Month == numberMonth-1) ////will mathematical calculation work here?
                                          .Select(i => new { i.Overtime })
                                          .ToList(); 

    // and now here is a problem how to sum all these values ​​.. 
    // preferably in HHH: mm format
    var thisValue = that this value would be written to the variable var;

    var viewModel = new ParentView { Model1 = karta };
    return PartialView("_TableViewEcp", viewModel); //change nothing
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class Karta_Model
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Login { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month{ get; set; }
        public int? DayOfMonth { get; set; }
        public string? Overtime { get; set; }
}

public partial class ParentView
{
    public List<Karta_Model> Model1 { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If you change your column's [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-ver15) from varchar to [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8), you won't have to **parse** every single record to accumulate the value. Then you can take advantage of Linq's `Sum()` method.

Comment: And don't forget the edge case for December/January in your logic.

Comment: \ December / Januarlogic we skip, since January it is 0, that's the point that I can't change to TimeSpan

Comment: Then you will parse every record's string e.g. `TimeSpan.Parse(s)` or create a helper function and add it to your Select projection.

Comment: and can I convert this string to timespan on the fly for calculations? only for calculations?

Comment: The string here is only useful for display -- you can't perform calculations on them nor can you easily alter its display format. A numeric value can be used in calculations and be displayed in arbitrary formats at display time.

Comment: and how to convert TimeSpan from HH: mm: ss (on sql server side) to HH: mm (on model side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your select to parse the strings to TimeSpans

```
.Select(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(i))
```

Then you can use Aggregate to sum the TimeSpans

```
.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2)
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TlXDB)